# Device Rotation in Degrees

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm working on an app that allows the user to rotate the iOS device like a steering wheel. I'm interested in getting a rough approximation of the degrees of the rotation (doesn't have to accurate at all). Is there an API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's called [Core Motion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/_index.html).